# Print zebra RW420 with variable height on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, zebra-printers

I have a problem when I try to print a ticket with zebra printer. It uses CPCL and I program manually the ticket. I have a "for loop" for printing different products. When I print, for example, 5 products, the ticket height isn't variable, that is, the height of the ticket is always de same and not printed all CPCL commands.

The products command in CPCL are "T180 0 3 x y Product_NAME"\r\n".

My configLabel is `! 0 200 200 639 1\r\n`, the 639 number is the height and always print a ticket with this height.
Is there any way to change this height to variable height depends on the height of the labels printed?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options as far as I can tell.

1. Programmatically determine the height of your receipt.  Instead of hard-coding the configuration to '639', determine a more appropriate height for this label by multiplying the number of products by some constant.  For example - if you have 3 products on your label, set the height to 3 * 100 = 300.  If you have 5, set it to 5 * 100 = 500.  You will have to tweak this to get a reliable length.
2. Use line-print mode.  Instead of indicating the label-size up front, you could potentially use line-print mode to simply print one line at a time.  Line print mode will cause each line of data received to be printed immediately.  Instead of sending CPCL (T180 0 3 x y....), you simply send the text you want printed.  Take a look here for an example on how to enable line print mode: https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO7296.  You can also find more details about line print mode in section 9-1 of the CPCL manual: http://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/printer/cpcl-pm-en.pdf